# SQL oracle plus

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to write a sub query that will return the names of those customers who were referred by the same individual who referred *Jorge Perez*

Here what I came with:

```
select firstname||' '||lastname "Customer Name",Referred
from book_customer
where Firstname='Jorge' and lastname=' Perez'
order by referred
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the table design? I think you need to map referred to an id of the book_customer but we can't write this query for you if you don't give us the table design.

Answer (score 2):

What you have looks like it will just return Jorge Perez and whoever referred him. You need something like:

```
select firstname, lastname
from book_customer
where Referred = (select Referred
                  from book_customer
                  where firstname='Jorge' and lastname='Perez')
```

Here I'm assuming `Referred` is just the id of a user.  The query above gets the first name and last name of those users who have the same referral id as Jorge Perez.

Comment: You're assuming that the table is unique on firstname + lastname, which is (hopefully) unlikely; and that the referred column refers to who referred Jorge, not who he has referred. The second is sort-of indicated in the question...

Comment: @Ben I hadn't assumed firstname + lastname uniqueness, but it doesn't really matter. Having `Referred` mean who Jorge was referred by is the only single-table design that makes sense. Otherwise you'd be duplicating Jorge's record for every person he referred.